# startActivityForResult can't work well when setResult is placed in onPause(), onStop() or onDestroy()

Tags: android

When I put *setResult()* in the *onClickListener* of a button, that works. However, if I put it in *onPause()*, *onStop()* or *onDestroy()*, that never works.

I got really confused about that.

Here is the code of MainActivity.

```
package com.example.hellotest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class), 0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "RESULT_OK");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "result not ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the SecondActivity.

```
package com.example.hellotest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//              setResult(RESULT_OK);
                Log.d(TAG, "button on click");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
//      setResult(RESULT_OK);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
//      setResult(RESULT_OK);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

And here is the Log of which I put *setResult()* in the *onClick()*

```
11-21 00:07:54.243: D/SecondActivity(4790): button on click
11-21 00:07:56.364: D/SecondActivity(4790): onPause
11-21 00:07:57.813: D/SecondActivity(4790): onStop
11-21 00:07:57.813: D/SecondActivity(4790): onDestroy

11-21 00:07:56.404: D/MainActivity(4790): RESULT_OK
```

But if in *onDestroy()*

```
11-21 00:10:08.125: D/SecondActivity(4846): onPause
11-21 00:10:09.456: D/SecondActivity(4846): onStop
11-21 00:10:09.456: D/SecondActivity(4846): onDestroy

11-21 00:10:08.176: D/MainActivity(4846): RESULT_CANCELED
```

I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `setResult()` when the user performs the operation that selects the result. `onPause()` or later lifecycle events are too late.

`startActivityForResult()` is designed for "picker" sorts of activities, where the user is picking something. The typical pattern is for you to call `setResult()` and `finish()` once the user has picked their item.

Answer (score 3):

You can also override `finish()` and set the result before calling into the super class:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    setResult(...);
    super.finish();   
}
```